# Взаимозаменяемые OpenVPN сервер на Mikrotik и Ubuntu 16.04, файлы конфигураций

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, mikrotik

Необходимы несколько OpenVPN серверов на базе платформ:

- Mikrotik
- Ubuntu

Требования к серверам OpenVPN что бы без проблем подключались все клиенты из списка ниже, без изменения клиентских конфигураций кроме имени/IP сервера, возможность назначать IP адреса каждому клиенту статически.

- Mikrotik
- Ubuntu
- Windows
- и возможно Android

Трафик между клиентами разрешить
Проблемы с сертификатами для клиентов и корневым думаю опускаются (с этим у меня проблем не возникло)

Сложность заключается в том что у Mikrotik нет поддержки сжатия lzo, протокола udp, еще в качестве клиента не умеет tap или tun (могу ошибаться, уже запутался)